# getById is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-test-renderer

When I try to simulate a click I am getting the error in the subject line.

My whole test file:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

import * as React from 'react';

import TestRenderer, {act} from 'react-test-renderer';
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import {jest} from '@jest/globals';

describe('parent component', () => {
    const component = TestRenderer.create(
        <Component/>,
      );
    it('renders correctly', () => {
        let tree = component.toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
    test('my click event', () => {
    const handleClick = jest.fn();
    const { getById } = TestRenderer.create(
        <Component onClick={handleClick}/>,
      );
    const button = getById('component-div-id');
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

The error points specifically to the `getById`:

TypeError: getById is not a function

```
  28 |         <Component onClick={handleClick}/>,
  29 |       );
> 30 |     const button = getById('component-div-id');
```

Comment: Are you trying to call document.getElementById?

Comment: yes, that is right @BlueSnow

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're combining two different test libraries, `TestRenderer` does not have a method called getById, but react testing library does have one that is called `getByTestId` that will look for an element that has the attribute `data-testid`.

For example if you have a div like this one:

`<div data-testid="component-div-id">A div</div>`

Do this

```
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";

const { getByTestId } = render (
    <Component onClick={handleClick}/>,
);
// Do the assertions
const button = getByTestId('component-div-id');
fireEvent.click(button);
```

In case you want to look by the actual id attribute like:

`<div id="component-div-id">A div</div>`

you have to do this:

```
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";

const component = render (
    <Component onClick={handleClick}/>,
);
// Do the assertions
const button = component.container.querySelector('#component-div-id');
fireEvent.click(button);
```